# Multiple table updates in a column with different set of values and condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to make the query below a single update instead of multiple updates. Some of the queries below are having two conditions. How should I create a single update?

```
CREATE TABLE t1(id INT identity, settingname NVarChar(100),settingvalue NVarChar(100),)
GO

INSERT t1(settingname, settingvalue) 
VALUES ('DefaultPortalContainer','Default Portal Container')
      , ('DefaultPortalSkin','Default Portal Skin')
      , ('DefaultAdminContainer','Default Admin Container')
      ,('DefaultAdminSkin','Default Admin Skin')
      ,('ForceLowerCase','No')
      ,('DefaultTabWorkflow', 'Not Set')

GO

UPDATE t1 
SET SettingValue = 'Blank' 
WHERE SettingName = 'DefaultPortalContainer' 

UPDATE t1
SET SettingValue = 'Content' 
WHERE SettingName = 'DefaultPortalSkin' 

UPDATE t1
SET SettingValue = 'Main' 
WHERE SettingName = 'DefaultAdminContainer' 

UPDATE t1
SET SettingValue = 'Edit'
WHERE SettingName = 'DefaultAdminSkin' 

UPDATE t1 SET settingvalue = 'Y' 
WHERE settingname ='ForceLowerCase' 
AND settingvalue != 'Y' 

UPDATE t1 SET settingvalue = 'All' 
WHERE settingname ='DefaultTabWorkFlow' 
AND settingvalue != 'Not Set'
```

Comment: Use CASE statement

Comment: I wouldn't do this as a single update statement. It isn't going to be any faster but the code will be way more complicated.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin, yes I can do it using CASE statement, but how I will implement the last  two updates having two conditions?

Comment: @SeanLange, ok so meaning making it a single update will have an impact or the same on performance?So I will leave it as it is?

Comment: I would just leave it as you have right now. Just make sure to send all those `UPDATE`s together in a single batch instead of making multiple roundtrips. Enclosing all of them within a transaction is very likely needed too.

Comment: @Alejandro, how should I send the updates in a single batch?

Comment: That's done client-side. Just call your DB library only once, with a query text containing all your updates together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still would not do this as a single update because it is a lot more difficult to maintain. And the performance isn't going to be any different (or at least extremely marginal). But you can do this using a case expression. Something like this.

```
UPDATE dbo.PortalSettings 
SET SettingValue = 
case 
    when SettingName = 'DefaultPortalContainer' then'Blank' 
    WHEN SettingName = 'DefaultPortalSkin' then 'Content' 
    WHEN SettingName = 'DefaultAdminContainer' THEN 'Main' 
    WHEN SettingName = 'DefaultAdminSkin' THEN 'Edit'
    WHEN SettingName = 'ForceLowerCase' AND SettingValue != 'Y' THEN 'Y'
    WHEN SettingName = 'DefaultTabWorkFlow' AND SettingValue != 'Not Set' THEN 'All' 
END
where SettingName in
(
    'DefaultPortalContainer'
    , 'DefaultPortalSkin'
    , 'DefaultAdminContainer' 
    , 'DefaultAdminSkin'
    , 'ForceLowerCase'
    , 'DefaultTabWorkFlow'
)
```

Comment: Or course I would simplify the ForceLowerCase setting and get rid of the check for 'Y'. Who cares? You are going to set it to Y when the value is anything else, why not just set it to Y and be done with it?

Comment: there are some process/logic(c# code) which sets the default values for setting before this query is called, the above query is part of the post process.

Comment: OK. Not sure what that has to do with anything though.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Lange, for your answer.